# Exception filter does not return custom message as response in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

In my nestjs app. I created an AllExceptions filter

```
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AllExceptionsFilter.name);

  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();
    const requestId = request.id || request.headers['X-Request-ID'] || 'N/A';
    const status =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const message =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getResponse()
        : 'Internal server error';
console.log('the custom error is', message, status)
    const errorLogMessage = `Request(ID: ${requestId}) to ${request.url} failed with status ${status}: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`;
    if (status >= 500) {
      this.logger.error(errorLogMessage);
    }
    if (status >= 400 && status < 500) {
      this.logger.warn(errorLogMessage);
    }
    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
          timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
          path: request.url,
          requestId,
          message: (message instanceof Object ? message : { message }) 

    })

 
  }
}
```

in my main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

When i test the an endpoint that should throw an error, i get the custom error in my console.log.

```
the custom error is,
 {
  statusCode: 400,
  message: 'Portfolio name must be unique. Please choose another name.',
  error: 'Bad Request'
} 400
```

But in postman, I only see Internal server error 500 as the response.
What am i doing wrong?